# save images in webbrowser control without redownloading them from the internet

Tags: c#, image, browser, save

Is it possible to save images in a webbroswer control directly to hard disk, without needing to download them again from the internet?

Let's say I navigate to a website that has 15 images. They are all viewed in my webbrowser, but how can I save them now without the need to download them?

Answer (score 13):

This is the only way I could find. Curious if anyone else has a better way.

Copied from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3206780/Re-Image-in-WebBrowser.aspx)

You have to add a reference to *Microsoft.mshtml* and of course wait for the document to finish loading. This will save the images loaded in a `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser1` component - even the ones you don't want.

```
IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2) webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
IHTMLControlRange imgRange = (IHTMLControlRange) ((HTMLBody) doc.body).createControlRange();

foreach (IHTMLImgElement img in doc.images)
{
  imgRange.add((IHTMLControlElement) img);

  imgRange.execCommand("Copy", false, null);

  using (Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap))
  {
    bmp.Save(@"C:\"+img.nameProp);
  }
}
```

Comment: hi ...thanks for replying,
i just hope that someone will come up with another solution, as i really cant use the clipboard like that ...

Comment: well if the clipboard is off limits, then other than going through the cache, the only other way may be to download the image again. But lets see what others come up with

Comment: Very useful. Might want to add the ability to save and restore the old clipboard data. `var clipboardData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();` before `foreach` and `Clipboard.SetDataObject(clipboardData);` after `foreach`.