# Copy an image from WebBrowser

Tags: c#, bitmap

```
    IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)browser.Document.DomDocument;
    HTMLBody body = (HTMLBody)doc.body;
    Bitmap testImage;

    foreach (IHTMLImgElement img in doc.images)
    {
        if (img.src.IndexOf("some text here", 0) != -1) 
        {
            IHTMLControlRange imgRange;
            imgRange = (IHTMLControlRange)body.createControlRange();
            imgRange.add((IHTMLControlElement)img);
            imgRange.execCommand("Copy", false, null);
            //captchaUrl = img.GetAttribute("src");
            testImage = (Bitmap)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
        }
    }
```

Hi guys, this is my third attempt at taking an image from the WebBrowser control. First I tried by src, this game me a bad image. Then I tried to inject javascript, wasen't successful. Now I am trying this. It is finding the image, but I cant convert it to a Bitmap.

Any help?

Edit: Code is c#

Edit Edit: I just put the WebBrowser control in question on the form to see a visual representation, and the image I am trying to pull isn't loading. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: which language is it? tag it properly please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [save images in webbrowser control without redownloading them from the internet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566898/save-images-in-webbrowser-control-without-redownloading-them-from-the-internet)

Comment: do you **have** to use the WebBrowser control, or your requirement is to save an image which is on the web? You might use a HttpWebRequest

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work. I have been looking for over 3 hours.

HTTPWebRequest will only complicate it more, the WebBrowser allows you to access the controls. HTTPWebRequest is just html.

Comment: well, I disagree. See my answer.

Comment: What doesn't work with the copy?  Also, why do you need the image that is displayed?  The most common request I see for this is because you are trying to process a captcha image.

Comment: Yes I am trying to access a captcha. It simply leaves the bitmap blank.

Comment: "It is finding the image, but I cant convert it to a Bitmap." -- what do you mean? What is the error? And what is the original image -- jpeg, png, what?

Comment: Hi, fixed it. The problem was I was not waiting for the WebBrowser to load, so I was reading an empty image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/*
 * A function to get a Bitmap object directly from a web resource
 * Author: Danny Battison
 * Contact: gabehabe@googlemail.com
 */

/// <summary>
/// Get a bitmap directly from the web
/// </summary>
/// <param name="URL">The URL of the image</param>
/// <returns>A bitmap of the image requested</returns>
public static Bitmap BitmapFromWeb(string URL)
{
    try {
        // create a web request to the url of the image
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        // set the method to GET to get the image
        myRequest.Method = "GET";
        // get the response from the webpage
        HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
        // create a bitmap from the stream of the response
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(myResponse.GetResponseStream());
        // close off the stream and the response
        myResponse.Close();
        // return the Bitmap of the image
        return bmp;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null; // if for some reason we couldn't get to image, we return null
    }
}
```

Comment: I already stated in the question that I have tried to get the image by URL, this doesn't work for my case. I need to get the image shown in web browser control.