# Saving image shown in web browser

Tags: c#, save, browser

Sorry for my bad English.

How can I save one of the images in my web Browser without redownload that image? Like ie 'Save

picture as' option? The browser has 'save picture as' in context menu but I want to save image

without using this option and want to save automatically. Thanks.

Comment: See here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566898/save-images-in-webbrowser-control-without-redownloading-them-from-the-internet?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source here [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3206780/Re-Image-in-WebBrowser.aspx)

```
IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2) webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
IHTMLControlRange imgRange = (IHTMLControlRange) ((HTMLBody) doc.body).createControlRange();

foreach (IHTMLImgElement img in doc.images)
{
     imgRange.add((IHTMLControlElement) img);

     imgRange.execCommand("Copy", false, null);

     using (Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap))
     {
         bmp.Save(@"C:\"+img.nameProp);
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. Can you please help me to save clicked image not all images?

Comment: @user1425882 sorry u have to ask an other question about this