# How to save dynamic image in WatIn

Tags: c#, .net, httprequest, watin

I am trying to save an image that changes **dynamically** with each request.

I tried WatIn and `HttpWebRequest` (getting new image)

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("www.test.com");
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(ImageCodePath))
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    int count;

    while ((count = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
    {
        fs.Write(bytes, 0, count);
    }
}
```

and (User32.dll) URLDownloadToFile (getting new image)

```
[DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern Int32 URLDownloadToFile(Int32 pCaller, string szURL, string szFileName, Int32 dwReserved, Int32 lpfnCB);
 URLDownloadToFile(0, "https://test.reporterImages.php?MAIN_THEME=1", ImageCodePath, 0, 0);
```

I looked in all the temp folders and still can't find the image.

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache),"Content.IE5");
```

Every time I try to save it the server builds a new image and returns it. If I right click on the image and choose:

> Save picture as...

It will save the picture. I need to somehow implement this method (Right-click, Save picture as...) in WatIn in IE, or somehow download it with `HttpRequest` from my HTML page without server interaction.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Read the question again,i know that it more easy to send me link to another aswer that i all ready know,but the problem that i have DYNAMIC image i can't download this with request because i will get a new/changed image.

Comment: I removed the SHOUTING in the beginning of the question. Your question is probably reopened soon. It's in the reopen review queue and already has 4 reopen votes. Just so you know =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i understand, the idea is to capture current CAPTCHA image on page in browser to bypass it by some text recognition (btw, strange idea). And no problem to get image url (it is always the same). In this case you can use API to access  browser cache.
Specifically for IE FindFirstUrlCacheEntry/FindNextUrlCacheEntry
It can help if your application hosts WebBrowser.

Comment: I can't find any good example for c#,but it seems exactly want i need.Do  you have an example with this method?

Comment: Oops :-(
Here is working snippet http://www.windows-tech.info/1/a94a62466c699e02.php (strange code formatting, but it works).
Unfortunately, when i tried to catch picture from http://captcha.com/demos/features/captcha-demo.aspx (http://demos.captcha.com/demos/features/BotDetectCaptcha.ashx with some additions for http get), enum function can't find cashed picture, only site and icon.
`
Source URL: Visited: user@http://captcha.com/demos/features/captcha-demo.aspx
Source URL: Visited: user@http://captcha.com/favicon.ico
`

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebClient`:

```
 using (var client = new WebClient())
 {
     client.DownloadFile("http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=3c6263c3453b", "so-sprites.png");
 }
```

If you provide an url to `html` page that contains an `img` that you want to download and not directly to an image you can still use a web client with two consecutive requests. First is to  scrap the image url from the page source (not required if url is static) and second to actually download the image.

Edit:

Sorry. It was not clear from the start. So you host a browser in your app and you see the actual image in it. You want to download the image you are seeing. Of course, making another request won't work because another image will be generated.

The solution depends on the web browser control that you use.
For `WebBrowser` (System.Windows.Forms) you can use `IHTMLDocument2`. See example here:

[Saving image shown in web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387235/saving-image-shown-in-web-browser)

Comment: Still getting a new image,in browser  i see one image,but  client.DownloadFile saving changed image.

Comment: here is the link of image https://reporter.gate2shop.com/lib/captcha/CaptchaSecurityImages.php?MAIN_THEME=1  if you click on it it will change each time,and the request and client.download brings you every time new image,and i can't download the same image that i see in first request.

Comment: Yae i use WatIn (browser emulator) I tried that,but in WatIn it is no working.